# Pocketsphinx Raspberry Pi error reading dmp file

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pocketsphinx, dmp

I'm trying to use pocketsphinx with python on a Raspberry Pi 2 B.

But when I create the Decoder and it tries to read the dmp file, it throws me that :

```
INFO: ngram_model_trie.c(562): ngrams 1=62304, 2=18541132, 3=23627127
calloc(23627127,8) failed from ngrams_raw.c(250)
```

And then the program ends, I also tried with the phone model and it perfectly works ! (but the recognition is poor).

Do you know what can be the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have enough memory to use this particular language model. You can use smaller model or convert your model to bin format before loading.

Comment: New pocketsphinx uses new language model code which is optimized for new binary format but not the dmp format: http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2015/07/new-language-model-binary-format/

Comment: But how to convert ? I can't because the same problem.

Comment: Convert on desktop, use on raspberry pi.